# Why would these TikZ images center differently in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf

Why would these two images -- which are the same thing -- center differently under LaTeX?

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\[
\left\{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \draw (1,1) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\right\} 
\]

\[
\left\{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
  \filldraw[fill=white,draw=black] (1cm,0cm) arc (0:360:1cm) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture} 
\right\} 
\]

\end{document}
```

As show here:

[image]

Comment: The two circles have different offsets from the baseline. So when braces are drawn, both will start at baseline but end at different heights.

Comment: The circle is centered at (1,1), while the arc is centered at (0,0).

Comment: Using `baseline` without an option is the same as `baseline=0` I think. Because of that and what John said, in the first case the bottom edge of the circle is placed on the baseline, while in the second case the center of the circle is on the baseline.